# simulate a transaction considering another pending transaction

Tags: wallets, contract-invocation, pending-transactions, etherjs, simulation

I have the following problem and have hard time to simulate it to get the answer.

Let say I have a 5 WETH tokens.

I sent transaction **X** with **nonce 1** to transfer **5 tokens** from **Account A** to **Account B**. This Transaction is in the ***pending*** pool and **not** mined yet.

Now I create another transaction **Y** with **nonce 2** to transfer **5 tokens** from **Account A** to **Account B**.

I want to simulate the transaction **Y** before sending it. I'm using *staticCall* from *etherjs v5/6* to do this.

Will the *simulation* of transaction **Y**:

1. Succeed because at the current time I have 5 tokens (transaction X not mined yet)
2. Fails with low nonce
3. Fails with insufficient balance because it calculate and consider the pending transaction X
4. others..

If the answer is 1 or 2 Are there some other ways, libraries or tools, which consider the related pending transactions when the simulation happen.

Update:
If this is not Standardised between all provider. Then maybe using Infura as provider

Thanks

Comment: The answer could depend on your provider. Can you please update the question to include which provider you are using?

Comment: Thanks @Milk i updated the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ethers6 `staticCall`, same as Ethers5 `callStatic` method, sends the [**`eth_call`**](https://docs.infura.io/networks/ethereum/json-rpc-methods/eth_call) RPC request. The `nonce` parameter is **not supported**, so it has no effect. The mempool for `eth_call` is completely ignored, and by default, the call is executed on the latest block, though you can specify a different block number.

So your second simulation will succeed, as the account still has enough balance on the `latest` block.

There is no easy way to take the `pendingTransactions` into consideration when performing the call. To simulate multiple transactions at once, I use the [Hardhats](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/guides/forking-other-networks) forking feature to execute the transactions locally (*in-memory*). So in this case after executing/simulating the `X` transaction, the `Y` transaction will fail. The benefit of such an approach is that you also get all the `Logs` which are emitted during the simulation.

Comment: thanks it looks good. i will wait 2 more days and then accept it :)